# YOLO darknet retrain does not even start saying it could not find *.txt in some *labels* directory

Tags: object-detection, yolo, darknet, dataset

I have been trying to retrain YOLOv3 on a custom dataset. I saved the *jpg* images and their corresponding *txt* annotation files in the same directory. I have set the my *.data* file, *.names* file and *.cfg* file appropriately as suggested in many tutorials online. Quite frustratingly, I have been running into the problem where it says `Couldn't open file: <some-path>/labels/<some file>.txt`. What is annoying here it seems to be looking for *.txt* files in some *labels* directory which neither exists, nor did I mention it anywhere. All my *.jpg* and *.txt* files are in a directory named *images* located at the same level as where the system is looking for this *labels* directory.

What is further annoying is if I do separate *.txt* files into a *labels* directory which is where the yolo darknet is looking for, this error goes away but the training never starts.

I have tried many different ways of specifying the paths, using different models, cfg files etc, but all in vain. Please help someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making many attempts from different angles, I found out the right way. The answer to the first question of organizing *images* and *labels* is contrary to what most tutorials online suggest. *labels* should be located in a separate directory from the *images*. The path to the each *.txt* file should differ from their corresponding *.jpg* only in the word *images*. For example, if the path to an image is `<path/to/somewhere/images/somewhere/xyz.jpg>`, the path to its corresponding label file should be `<path/to/somewhere/labels/somewhere/xyz.txt>`.

As an answer to the second part where the training does not start, make sure to use argument `-clear 1` at the end of the darknet training command, i.e. `./darknet detector train  cfg/data_file.data cfg/cfg_file.cfg yolov3.weights -clear 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, in your *.data file, you have the following settings:

```
classes = [Your number of classes]
train  = data/train.txt
valid  = data/test.txt
names = data/obj.names
backup = backup/
```

You should have `data/train.txt`and `data/test.txt`, which is a text file containining the directory list of your images.

For example, if you put all of your images and txt files at data/obj, the txt file should contain:

```
data/obj/1.jpg
data/obj/2.jpg
.
.
(and so on)
```

Then, YOLO will automatically check the corresponding label of the images, which should be having the same name (in this case: 1.txt, 2.txt, ...)

Reference:
(No. 3 and 4 in https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects)